# list-style disc not applying to first li on chrome

Tags: css

When trying to style lists to use discs on right hand side (#details), the first li doesn't display the disc.

http://garden.paperfish.co/index.php/products/captan-50wp

Anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: plz supply some code samples HERE in your post, when your issue gets fixed, this question wont be of use to anyone. so post code here and if you really want to link something link a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: are they all included in the same ul? If you want it on all li use this:

`li{list-style:disc;}` if you want it on a certain div use this: `#yourdiv{list-style:disc;}`

Answer (score 3):

Add {clear : both} to ul

```
div#product-entry div#product-content ul {clear: both;}
```

Its caused by H2 element above ul - incorrect width.